# Swift: "Attempt to present ViewController whose view is not in the window hierarchy" when using presentViewController inside a delegate method

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, delegates

I am using a custom cell class with a button in it.

```
import UIKit

protocol TouchDelegateForShotsCell {
    func touchedTwitterButton()
}

class ShotsCell : UITableViewCell {

    let touchDelegateForShotsCell: TouchDelegateForShotsCell = MasterViewController()

    @IBAction func twitterButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
         touchDelegateForShotsCell.touchedTwitterButton()
    }
}
```

When the button is pressed I call a delegate function in the MasterViewController which contains the following standard code for sharing on Twitter:

```
func touchedTwitterButton() {
    var shareToTwitter :SLComposeViewController = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeTwitter)
    self.presentViewController(shareToTwitter, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I receive the error :

> "Attempt to present ViewController whose view is not in the window hierarchy!".

I've tried several workarounds. For example, creating a separate view controller and performing a segue from the button. That works in part, however, when I try to pass data I get another error :

> "'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: Receiver ViewController has no segue with identifier 'segueToTwitterShare'".

Which isn't true.  For this I tried deleting my app and restarting xcode which worked for some people.  However, the problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

```
let touchDelegateForShotsCell: TouchDelegateForShotsCell = MasterViewController()
```

It's not the good `delegate`. When you write `MasterViewController()` you *create a new instance* of `MasterViewController` (so it is not in the window hierarchy) but you don't pass the intense *who is executed*.

I suggest you an example to better understand what is the problem and see where changes is needed.

I add an `init()` function into `ShotsCell` :

```
class ShotsCell : UITableViewCell {

    var touchDelegateForShotsCell: TouchDelegateForShotsCell!

    init(withDelegate delegate: MasterViewController){
        super.init(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "cellIdentifier")

        touchDelegateForShotsCell = delegate
    }

    @IBAction func twitterButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        touchDelegateForShotsCell.touchedTwitterButton()
    }
}
```

And pass your `MasterViewController` to your cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` :

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = ShotsCell(withDelegate: self)

    return cell
}
```

Hope that helps. It works for me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  super.init() is not the designated initializer so I changed it to super.init(style: <UITableViewCellStyle>, reuseIdentifier: <String?>) but I get the error expected ',' separator when I enter values for style and reuseIdentifier.

Comment: Can you possibly post a link to a sample project?

Comment: I updated my answer to match your code however I can't reproduce this error : modification of `super.init()` to `super.init(style:, reuseIdentifier:)` works for me.